# CSS: How to place the element straight right (see the picture)?

Tags: html, css

How can I place an arrow (in red circle) straight to the right and in the middle of table?

[image]

*UPDATE*

The link to my html code `jsfiddle .net/4j679a7t`

Comment: Do you have any code to start off? There is a plenty ways...

Comment: you're going to have to be more specific what you want, and also include the relevant html and the css you've tried

Comment: What have you tried so far? My suggestion is place it in a full height column and give it a `margin:auto 0;`

Comment: absolute positioning I believe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/aedagn95/

The HTML

```
<div class="table-wrap"> <a class="arrow-top" href="#">&uarr;</a>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.table-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.table-wrap table {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.arrow-top {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px; /* The half of your element height */    
}
```